# Access inline SVG's transformed group bounding box (x and y position, width and height)?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Is there an "easy" DOM way to get a group's transformed position (center or origin) and bounding box (width, height)?

`<g>` as a logical container tag does not have geometric attributes aside from `transform`, which its children use.

```js
let o = document.getElementById("o");
let g = document.getElementById("g");

o.textContent += "rect  x = " + r.x.baseVal.value + "\n";
o.textContent += "group x = " + g.x.baseVal.value + "\n";  // TypeError: g.x is undefined
```

```css
svg{background-color:#f3f3f3}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200">
<g id="g" transform="translate(100,100)" >
  <rect id="r" width="100" height="100" ></rect>
</g>
</svg>
<div id="o"></div>
```

So it probably is required to iterate all children and calculate the sum of their bounding boxes (including transforms)?

---

Edit:

The following returns the group's bounding box **without** the transform:

```js
let o = document.getElementById("o");
let g = document.getElementById("g");

o.textContent += "getBBox().x = " + r.getBBox().x + "\n";
o.textContent += "getBBox().y = " + r.getBBox().y + "\n";
o.textContent += "getBBox().width = " + r.getBBox().width + "\n";
o.textContent += "getBBox().height = " + r.getBBox().height + "\n";
```

```css
svg{background-color:#f3f3f3}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200">
<g id="g" transform="translate(100,100)" >
  <rect id="r" width="100" height="100" ></rect>
</g>
</svg>
<div id="o"></div>
```

Comment: call getBBox. That works on a <g> and also on individual leaf elements.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, now the result just needs to be transformed - do you happen know of a method for that, too?

Comment: create a parent <g> element and get that element's bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox

> The SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox() allows us to determine the
>   coordinates of the smallest rectangle in which the object fits. The
>   coordinates returned are with respect to the current svg space, i.e.
>   after the application of all geometry attributes on all the elements
>   contained in the target element.

But also:

> The returned value is a SVGRect object, which defines the bounding
>   box. This value is **irrespective of any transformation** attribute
>   applied to it or the parent elements.